# Vertical TextView positioning after rotation

Tags: android, android-layout

While I'm working on a Vertical `TextView`, I have one of two solutions:

1. Normal TextView with rotation -90: this makes the control of the
   position is too hard and with unexpected results due to the
   different sizes of devices
2. Custom Vertical TextView, but I don't have an idea about doing that.

Any suggestions or solutions?

the following code will cause the text view to have a center position, what if I need to make the vertical view to be at the right end of the screen and centralized vertically?

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/descriptionTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|end"
        android:rotation="-90"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        tools:text="Please Center your image" />
```

Comment: any sample do you have

Comment: can you explain what you said over here "what if i need to make the vertical view to be in the right end of the screen and centralized vertically?"

Comment: No sample yet. I need to know if i can have a control over the position of the text after rotation. it will be rotated according to its center. If I need it to position it in the right with center vertical after rotation then I need to put Text center  center at the right and center position before rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Custom Class Which help You,

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by DB Solanki on 22/3/18.
 */

public class VTextView extends TextView {
    final boolean isTop;
    public VTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        final int mGravity = getGravity();
        if(Gravity.isVertical(mGravity) && (mGravity&Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == Gravity.BOTTOM) {
            setGravity((mGravity&Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK) | Gravity.TOP);
            isTop = false;
        }else
            isTop = true;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int mWidthMeasureSpec, int mHeightMeasureSpec){
        super.onMeasure(mHeightMeasureSpec, mWidthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b){
        return super.setFrame(l, t, l+(b-t), t+(r-l));
    }
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas mCanvas){
        if(isTop){
            mCanvas.translate(getHeight(), 0);
            mCanvas.rotate(90); //Here rotate view to 90degree
        }else {
            mCanvas.translate(0, getWidth());
            mCanvas.rotate(-90);
        }
        mCanvas.clipRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), android.graphics.Region.Op.REPLACE);
        super.draw(mCanvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfect for me.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did like this

try like this :-

```
             <TextView
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:text="Abhinav Gupta"/>
```

Take `height` according to `text` and take `width` according to `textSize`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a pivot position to your text.

```
android:transformPivotX="200dp"
```

Comment: This will make it depend on the width of the screen. which might cause undesirable position